# Can you change the way 2d arrays are ordered in C++/CUDA

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, cuda

Suppose I have a two dimensional array in C++ under CUDA, stored in the shared memory,
like so:

```
__shared__ float arr[4][4]; // C++ has a default row-major ordering
```

By default C++ will order the elements in `arr` in a row-major format.

That is it will allocate a continuous block of memory and store the elements like this (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,0), (1,1), ... and so on...

Is there a way to tell the C++/CUDA compiler to arrange this in a column-major order?

Comment: Probably not.  The C++ compiler is unlikely to do that; I doubt if the CUDA part of the system can do anything about it either.

Comment: I don't think you can, but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just swap indexes you are using?

Instead of using `arr[x][y]` use `arr[y][x]`.

Interesting is why you would like to do this. Maybe using cache memory could be helpful but I can't tell for sure without details.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

Transpose the matrix. `arr[4][4]` means that `arr` is an array of 4 arrays of size 4. The reason to store the values in "row-major" ordering is that `arr[0]`, for example, must give us the pointer to the first of these four arrays, and elements of a single array should be placed in contiguous memory locations so that they can be individually referenced by adding an index to a unique identifier.